# Looking for to achieve a specific animation by jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i have page where i have 3 div. one is main div and other 2 is child div position in main div. one child div is called left div and other child div is called right div. here i am pasting image as a result people can see what kind of output i am looking for.

[image]

suppose i have two button called show and hide. when i will click on show button then a div will be generated dynamically and appear with slide in effect like slide to left side of right div and cover the right div like overlay and same way when i will click on hide button then dynamic overlay div will slide to right side and uncover the right div. hence i was searching Google a lot for getting similar thing but still got nothing. it would be great help if someone help me to do it.

thanks

### Edit

thanks to @Jamie Barker.he provide sample code which is close to my requirement. here i am pasting his code.

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="left">

    </div>
    <div id="right">

    </div>
</div>
<span id="animate">Click me to Animate</span>

#main {
    width:400px;
    padding:5px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border:1px solid #000;
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
}
#main > div {
    width:calc(50% - 10px);
    border:1px solid #000;
    position:absolute;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    height:calc(100% - 10px);
}
#main #left {
    left:5px;   
    background:red;
    opacity:0.5;    
}
#main #right {
     right:5px;   
    background:yellow;
    opacity:0.5;    
}
#animate {
    margin:10px 0 0 0;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    background:#666;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#fff;
    padding:2px 5px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

$('#animate').click(function() {
    if ($('#left').css('left')==='5px') {  
        $('#left').css({'z-index':'1000'});
        $('#left').animate({
            left: $('#right').offset().left - 10
        }, 500, function() {
            console.log('moved right');    
        });
    } else {
        $('#left').animate({
            left: '5'
        }, 500, function() {
            console.log('moved left');    
        });        
    }
});
```

jsfiddle link as follows http://jsfiddle.net/wswb2v1t/8/

if anyone run the code then he/she will see left side div slide to right and cover the right div but that is not my requirement. i want a div will be generated dynamically at right side and slide to left just to cover right side div. how to modify the above code achieve the same.

thanks

Comment: your tried code please?

Comment: You would use js to toggle classes on the divs which have transitions associated with them. Show your current code if you need help further.

Comment: the main problem is i can generate html and also knows how to generate div dynamically but the main problem is where to position the overlay div and how to drag the div from right to left just to cover the right div with something like overlay effect.

Comment: If you possesed the knowledge you said you do in your comments, you should be able to work the rest out yourself. This is a Question and Answer site, not a "please write some code for me" site.

Comment: http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using JQuery, you can use JQuery UI to add more easing effects for the animate function which should do what you're looking for:

http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: the main problem is i can generate html and also knows how to generate div dynamically but the main problem is where to position the overlay div and how to drag the div from right to left just to cover the right div with something like overlay effect.

Comment: You could use Absolute CSS positioning? see this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wswb2v1t/8/)...

Comment: why u used this clear:left; in css....i just omit this but all works fine. would u plzz explain the significance of this clear:left;. thanks